# How many custom parameters can be registered in firebase analytics?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

How many custom parameters can be registered in firebase analytics?

Firebase Analytics below.

Each parameter that you specify counts toward the project limit of 50. For example, if you specify the same parameter for 3 different events, then that counts as 3 of your 50

I know that there are 10 letters and 40 numbers per project. It is also noted in the article that the same parameters can be added to different events. I have created a custom parameter called `member_type` and set it equal to the two events `a_button_click` and `b_button_click`. However, if you add in the custom parameter report on the Firebase console, it will be treated as a different parameter, reaching the text +2 and quickly reaching the limit (text 10). Can not I have custom parameters sent to me in the report?

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("member_type", article_type);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("a_button_click", bundle);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("member_type", article_type);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("b_button_click", bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the limit of 50 custom parameters (10 string and 40 int) has been removed. You can update firebase pod/dependency and then try to send more than 10 string custom parameters and they will work like charm. This is the reason it is not written in documentaion about the limit.